# What does $[-\pi \; \pi]$ band-limited signal mean?

Tags: discrete-signals, bandwidth

I know that a band-limited signal is a signal which have a limited set of frequencies.

What is then the  relation between band limiting and $[-\pi \; \pi]$  since $-\pi$ and $\pi$ are related to angles and frequencies are in Hertz ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now first of all concept of **bandlimited** signal exists in the context of analog signals not digital ones. Digital signals are always (by their definition and existance) bandlimited.

Second, frequency in analog signals is expressed either as $f$ in Hertz (cycle per second, repetation per second) or as $\Omega$ in radians per second, where they are related as $$\Omega = 2 \pi f$$ So for example a frequency of $f=1$ kHz would equivalently make a radian-frequency of $\Omega=2 \pi 1k \approx 6283$ rad/sec.

When a bandlimited analog signal $x_a(t)$ is sampled by a period of $T_s$ (and digitized afterwards in practice), the resulting discrete-time sequence $x[n]$ will have a discrete Fourier transform expression of 
$$ H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1}{T_s} \sum_k X_a( \frac{\omega + 2\pi k}{T_s})$$

such that it will be frequency **normalized** to the discrete-time frequency range of $-\pi \leq \omega < \pi$. Where $\omega$ is the discrete-time frequency in radians per sample. Where $X_a$ is the continuous-time Fourier transform (frequency content) of the analog signal $x_a(t)$.

for $k=0$ the base period of $H(e^{j \omega})$ becomes $$ H(e^{j \omega}) = \frac{1}{T_s} X_a( \frac{\omega}{T_s}) $$ where the frequency normalization becomes more apparent as setting $ \Omega = \frac{\omega}{T_s} $ yields the those analog radian-frequencies for $X_a(\Omega)$ when $\omega$ of $H(e^{j \omega})$ is selected from $\omega \in [-\pi,\pi)$

Comment: In other words saying, that  a signal is -pi ou band limited means that it is a sampled signal?

Comment: no it's not. if a signal is stated as **bandlimited to $\pi$ radians per second**.then It's still a continuous time bandlimited analog signal whose bandwidth is $W=\pi$ rad/sec. Discrete-time signals are never described as **bandlimited** (unless you are talking about digital sample-rate conversion systems). However a discrete-time signal's Fourier transform can be nonzeros only for $|w| < \omega_0$ and zero otherwise can be considered to be confiend to a range of (band of) frequencies w.

Answer (score 2):

$\pi$ is much more that something related to angles. Frequencies in Hertz are reciprocal to time in seconds.

But for an abstract function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, taken as a model of generic continuous-variable signals,  ie without unit in the first ordinal variable, it does makes sense to be band-limited with a unitless constant bounding the interval in frequency.

The characterization of band-limited signals is given by the Paley-Wiener theorem.